# override the existing line in linux output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdout

I have the following code:

```
echo "some output"

while true ; do 
  echo "running"
  ./call-me.sh
  echo "all done. ctrl+c to exit"
  sleep 5
done
```

I want to give the user the option to exit the script without worry about failing `call-me.sh`.
This scripts results in something like:

```
some output
running
all done. ctrl+c to exit
running
all done. ctrl+c to exit
running
all done. ctrl+c to exit
running
all done. ctrl+c to exit
running
all done. ctrl+c to exit
running
all done. ctrl+c to exit
^C
```

I want to only show one line in the output, either `running` if `call-me.sh` is running or `all done. ctrl+c to exit`. I don't want to use `clear` as this is a part of a script and I want to leave the rest of the output as is.
To sum up - I want to edit the last output line with new one.
So the output will be either:

```
some output
running
```

or

```
some output
all done. ctrl+c to exit
```

Ideas?

I'm going to add a "stop file". if exits the script will delete it and exit.

Comment: Use `printf '\033[1A\033[K'` to clear the previous line.

Comment: this is great @Darkman ! please post an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Well, @Nir you might not know this - but you can't answer on a question that has been closed for whatever reasons. And in this case, it is not needed I think.

Comment: Oh I did not see it was close.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to the following, see if this works
test.sh has the following code

```
 while true ; do
      clear
      ./call-me.sh
      echo "\033[Kall done. ctrl+c to exit"
      sleep 5
    done
```

call-me.sh

```
printf "running\r"
sleep 10
```

See if this works for your case

Comment: have you read my last paragraph? i've edit my question so it will be clearer